How should I share the results of playtesting homebrew from a previous Homebrew Review question?
I appreciate the advice given in this answer to the question How can I ask a good homebrew review question?. The final recommendation, "Try playtesting, and share the results if you have," includes some brief advice on playtesting but none on sharing. Assuming I've done a decent job of playtesting my homebrew, how do I do a good job of sharing these results back to the community?
This answer is an excellent start/reference in that it describes what is useful in a typical homebrew review answer.
I'm interested in receiving general advice like the linked answers above are for their questions, but there are a few specific questions that have occurred to me:

Should I share playtesting results as an answer to the original homebrew review question or somewhere else?
If the homebrew's features iterate substantially during playtesting, should that be handled as a new question (and if so, how to define "substantially")? Note that the linked answer above recommends opening new questions when you iterate on homebrew (though I suspect this advice is more about not invalidating existing answers than about organization).
How should the results be formatted, and what is vital to include?



Should I share playtesting results as an answer to the original homebrew review question or somewhere else

As an answer to the original question. The results of your playtest of the material in question should generally answer the original question. If you tested the homebrew class you asked a question about, and your playtest results address the problem(s) outlined in your question, then you have a good, and probably the best, answer to the question.

If the homebrew's features iterate substantially during playtesting, should that be handled as a new question (and if so, how to define "substantially")? Note that the linked answer above recommends opening new questions when you iterate on homebrew (though I suspect this advice is more about not invalidating existing answers than about organization).

You can still put this in an answer to the original question. An answer of the form “I made X changes to Y feature for Z reasons that came up during playtesting” is, again, going to be more helpful and insightful than our armchair reviews based on broader experience and not playtesting. You only need a new question if you’re actually asking a new question, such as soliciting review of your modifications to the original homebrew in question.

How should the results be formatted, and what is vital to include?

Format it any way you like; you’re free to express yourself. Just don’t use code blocks. Commentary on all the individual components of the original would be nice, and we like details. If your answer is just “I play tested it and it was fine”, it will probably get downvotes, but that doesn’t need explaining. The more detail the better.
